# create a soft link to every file

Tags: bash

I am trying to create a soft link in a directory (let's call it new/ ) to every file that are named (Roosvelt001_sometest.png //Roosvelt002_sometest.png // Roosvelt003_sometest.png // Roosvelt004_sometest.png // Roosvelt005_sometest.png  // Roosvelt006_sometest.png) to another directory  (let's call it old/) such that link name does not contain the words ('sometest')‘_and the word ('rooselvelt’) is replaced by ('Franklin') and extension is ‘.tiff’ instead of ‘.png’.

I tried `for i in /home/usr/old/Roos* ; do ln -s $i /home/usr/new/ ; done`

but I cannot change the files. Do you have a proposition ?
Best regards

Comment: Links can be renamed after they  have been created.

Answer (score 4):

I'd use a bash regular expression to capture the number from the filename:

```
for file in /path/to/old/Roosvelt*; do
    if [[ $file =~ Roosvelt([0-9]+) ]]; then
        ln "$file" /path/to/new/Franklin${BASH_REMATCH[1]}.tiff
    fi
done
```

Comment: I do not understand the bahs_rematch command[1]. It does not work for me. Maybe I do something wrong

Comment: BASH_REMATCH is an array variable that is populated with the captured parts of a successful regular expression match.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I've come with `find`:

```
find /path/old/ -name "Roosvelt*" -exec sh -c 'ln -s {} /path/new/$(basename {} | sed -e 's/Roosvelt/Franklin/' -e 's/_sometest.png/.tiff/')' \;
```